# What is the fastest way to clone object several times

Tags: c#, deserialization, cloning

I need to clone pretty big object several times and I am finding the faster way to do it.

Now I use serialization by `BinaryForamter` into `MemoryStream`. So here is how I would like to use feature I am speaking about (`DeserializeToList` is method I am looking for):

```
var originalObject = new MyClass();
var objectClones = new List<MyClass>();
var cloneCount = 10;

var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
  formatter.Serialize(stream, originalObject);
  stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  objectClones = (MyClass)formatter.DeserializeToList(formatter, cloneCount);
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
I don't want to change `MyClass`. That's why I use binary serialization. So `MyClass.Clone` isn't solution for now.

**UPDATE 2:**
I don't want to even touch `MyClass` or them properties. So manually properties copying isn't way I am looking for.

Comment: If your objects are as big as you suggest, keep in mind that this solution will need roughly 3x as much memory to perform the clone operation. OriginalObject + MemoryStream + CloneObject. You can probably get faster performance and better memory utilization by manually cloning the fields you need.

Comment: @BradleyUffner yes, that's right. But I wouldn't like change `MyClass` for now

Comment: Check out serialization surrogates then. It allows you to do manual binary serialization without modifying the original class. It can be a little complicated thought

Comment: @BradleyUffner could you please explain more how you suggest to use  serialization surrogates

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension methods for this purpose if you don't want to touch the original class.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class MyClassExtensions
{
    public static MyClass Clone(this MyClass obj)
    {
        return new MyClass()
        {
            Name = obj.Name
        };
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
var originalObj = new MyClass() { Name = "Original" };
var clonedObj = originalObj.Clone();
Console.WriteLine(clonedObj.Name); // Name = "Original"
```

Comment: I can change `MyClass` but I don't want to do it. So workaround like extension method isn't better than ordinary `Clone` method.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test about the benchmark's performance, but why don't implement Clone interface?

```
public interface ICloneable<T>
{
    T Clone();
}

public class ComplessObj : ICloneable<Book>
{
    public string f1;
    public int f2;
    .. and so on

    public ComplessObj Clone()
    {
        return new ComplessObj { /* set properties f1,f2 ..*/ };
    }
}
```

and every time you want deep clone list of your complex object

You can use LINQ

```
List<ComplessObj> ComplessObj_2 = ComplessObj.Select(co => co.Clone()).ToList();
```

or

```
List<ComplessObj> ComplessObj_2 = ComplessObj.ConvertAll(co => co.Clone());
```

Comment: Thank you for comment, but I don't want change `MyClass`